# Is it safe to share `auth_user` and `django_session` table for intranet Django projects?

Tags: django, single-sign-on

We've lots of intranet projects written in Django. As projects grows auth is always painful and duplicated.

E.g. user needs to login to three internal systems:

http://192.168.x.x/proj1/

http://192.168.x.x/proj2/

http://192.168.x.x/proj3/

Basically he has to create three accounts on three systems. So I figured if the MySQL table  `auth_user` and `django_session` could be shared (using MySQL federated table engine) across three django projects, login session and info could be shared. So create account once and login one and use all three systems.

Is it safe? Anyone done similar in practice?

Comment: I have never done that before but I don't see any harm in having a common table of registered users. However you can sill have individual auth tables in projects and have access to the common table you uniquely maintain.. whenever a user log in for the first time, you copy the respective data from shared table into proj table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing auth and session tables is quite an acceptable solution as long as maintainers of each project are aware of this architecture.

Some issues to be aware of:

- Each project needs to be aware of the data stored in session by the other projects in order not to overwrite it inadvertently. This is not an issue if you only use the session for authentication.
- The [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/messages/) will not work as expected. Again, this might not be an issue in your projects.
- It's probably a good idea to use the same Django version across all projects. For example, Django 1.6 [changed the way it stores sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization) by default. The User model might also change between versions.
- If you want to use a [Custom User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), you need to use the same model on all projects. This might be a good option if you need to share extra profile data across projects though.

Since all three projects will have access to the DB, you'd better consider those as a single project/entity from a security point of view. Some data may leak from one project to the other through the session and be exposed where it shouldn't.

Also, some security issues may arise: if for example two projects use inadvertently the same variable name to store conflicting data, considered safe by one project but unsafe by another, a user could inject malicious data which will be considered safe.

But these things could happen if you have a single project maintained by multiple programmers too. So, as long as you make sure these are not issues for your projects you should be fine.

Comment: Any particular security issues that might arise? I am interested to know about them

Comment: Since all three projects will have access to the DB, you'd better consider those as a single project/entity from a security point of view. Some data may leak from one project to the other through the session and be exposed where it shouldn't. And some security issues may arise: if for example two projects use inadvertently the same variable name to store conflicting data, considered safe by one project but unsafe by another, a user could inject malicious data which will be considered safe. But these things could happen if you have a single project maintained by multiple programmers too.

Comment: @NicolasCortot thanks for the info. It's intranet and three projects are developed by the same team. So those concerns are legit but acceptable tradeoff.